# On the slope of a strictly increasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

If $f$ is a strictly increasing function, shouldn't $f'$ be always positive and never zero? Apparently there's this situation where the derivative can be $0$ if it's only at discrete points and not an interval.

How is that possible, when strictly increasing functions are, by definition, never of a zero slope?

Comment: $f(x)=x^{3}$ is an example.

Comment: Given any two real numbers $x_1 < x_2$ a function *f* is strictly increasing if $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$. Zero-derivatives at isolated points don't violate this definition. As Kavi mentions, the derivative of $f(x) = x^3$ at *x* = 0 is 0 but $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"strictly increasing functions are, by definition, never of a zero slope": that is not the definition of a strictly increasing function. The correct one says

$$x_0<x_1\implies f(x_0)<f(x_1).$$

Geometrically, this can be expressed as "the slope of any chord is positive", but not as "the slope of any tangent is positive".

Comment: Good succinct answer. I was wondering if "secant line" would be a better term than "chord" here, but I guess either term is fine.

Comment: So the only difference between strictly increasing and monotonically/plain increasing functions is that the latter can have whole intervals of zero slope?

Answer (score 2):

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing if, for every $b > a$, it follows that $f(b) > f(a)$.  This of course is satisfied by $f(x) = x^3$, since if $b > a$ implies $$f(b) - f(a) = b^3 - a^3 = (b - a)(a^2 + ab + b^2) = \frac{1}{4}(b-a)\left((b-a)^2 + 3(b+a)^2\right).$$  Since $b-a > 0$ and no square is negative, all factors are positive, thus $f(b) - f(a) > 0$.

However, $f'(x) = 3x^2$ so $f'(0) = 0$.